# Can't get VBA to write "http://"as text?

Tags: vb.net, http, text

I wrote the code bellow and need the asociated .PGP file to have the text http:// included. the PGP file is namely read by Autocad which requers the "http://" in its text to be able to launch the desierd webpage. problem is , is that VBA is Auto formating the http:// as a code entatie and not writting it to the text based PGP file.

Can any one tell me how to achive what im after?

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test.pgp"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine((TextBox5.Text) + "," + "     " + "START http://" + (TextBox6.Text) + ", 1,,")
        objWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("The acad.pgp file was successfully appended…")
    Else
        MsgBox("File missing reinstall or contact vendor…")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by `VBA is auto formating the http:// as a code entity`? (As an aside, you're using VB.NET, not VBA)

Comment: no im ussing VBA and everytime i typeout http:// even if in texte brackets (regardless of having START next to it) VBA is Autocorrecting the http:// with an underline and its not being written to the pgp (text based file)

Comment: Correction YES VBA is Autoformating it as a code entaty!

Comment: @habiel: Have you tried creating a file in Notepad with the same text as your application is creating and then trying to load that?

Comment: @habiel The code you've produced here is not VBA.  VBA is a language and doesn't do anything.  You appear to be misdiagnosing the problem.

Comment: yeah but lets say i use Appels for textbox5 and Bananas for textbox6 i get the text file displaying "Appels, START Bananas, 1,," and not the rquierd "Appels, START http:// Bananas, 1,," ?

Comment: Secondly Yeah as far as i know the program i used to create this code is called Visualbasics by microsoft, the only exception being is thta i use the express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'tried your code above in VisualStudio 2010. An empty file named `C:\test.pgp` was appended with the following text:

```
textbox5,     START http://textbox6, 1,,
```

The text http... is right there. Sometimes, when I open the file in a viewer, this viewer automatically detects the `http` string and marks it as a hyperlink. But only in this viewer!

So the error seems to be somewhere else, not in the code?